# file doen't appear on git repository

Tags: git, repository

i've trying to set git server/client

my setting on:

> **SERVER (ubuntu 12.04)**
>
> - folder web in: /web/site
> - git:  /web/site/site.git
> - git init --bare <<<
>     ***in site.git folder***
>
> **CLIENT (Mac OSX 10.7)**
>
> - mkdir /Application/MAMP/htdocs/site
> - cd site
> - git init
> - touch README
> - git add README
> - git commit -m 'tambah README'
> - git remote add origin ssh://doni@192.168.1.137/web/site/site.git
> - git push origin master

why on server side, my README file doesn't appear? i just found site.git folder

> doni@192.168.1.137's password:
>
> Counting objects: 3, done.
>
> Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 209 bytes, done.
>
> Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> To ssh://doni@192.168.1.137/web/site/site.git
>
> - [new branch]      master -> master

Thanks before :)

Regards,

doni

Answer (score 1):

A bare repository does not contain a working directory.

You can nevertheless review the current files on the master branch by using

`git ls-tree -r master`

This will list all objects recursively. Your README file will show up there.

Another way is to clone the repository to another directory. But if you just want to verify that everything is there, this is unnecessary.

Comment: hello EinLama, in SERVER, i get 100644 blob 90e527634a76133a3de8e8193ab59e97bbaca72d README with your syntax. but where is the file? :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a bare repository on the server side. A bare repository contains no working files.